# Comparing numbers in Array

Tags: ios

I have an array of core data objects called samples, each sample has a depthFrom and depthToo. I load each sample into a tableView to show the depthFrom and Too. I need to check for gaps between the values and if there is, insert a new sample.

The samples in the table could look like below with depthFrom and depthToo,

[image]

The issue is since there is a gap between the numbers from 100 to 210 new samples should be added to the table. using a gap of 50 as much as possible so it would look like this with the auto generated samples.

[image]

What im unsure of is how to compare the values, i would rather do it as the view loads before cellForRowAtIndexPath is called so i would not need to reload the table again. I was thinking of looping through each value and comparing them but there all in the same array so im not sure how i would do this. I have all the data displaying correctly in my app its just the gaps i need to account for and if im able to find a way to compare the values in the array then i can manage adding in the new objects i just need pointing in the right direction as this is new to me.

If theres anything about my question that is confusing then just add a comment and i will update it accordingly, thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like a for loop, while keeping tracking of the last `depthTo` and comparing to the current `depthFrom`. Can you post how you've already tried to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the gaps, you must keep track of the last `depthTo` and check if there's a gap between it and the current sample. If there is, insert samples with a spacing of 50*, until we reach our current sample.

Here's a pseudocode solution:

```
samples = NSMutableArray

int lastDepthTo = 0;

for (i = 0; i < [samples count]; i++) {
    s = samples[i]

    // add missing samples (upto current s.depthFrom)
    while (s.depthFrom > lastDepthTo) {

        genDepthTo = MIN(d.depthFrom, lastDepthTo+50)
        generated = new sample(depthFrom: lastDepthTo, depthTo: genDepthTo)
        [samples insert:generated atIndex:i]

        i++ // increment i to skip inserted sample
        lastDepthTo = genDepthTo
    }

    lastDepthTo = s.depthTo
}
```

Note: this is untested, maybe off by 1 for the indexing of i.

Comment: This was just what i needed, Thank you.